# Is this a good way to tidy up external modules in a python package

Tags: python

I have always been a bit bothered by having external modules such as numpy, pandas etc appearing as subsubmodules of submodules in packages I put together (since I invoke these inside the submodules by import numpy etc).

Recently I have taken on the following approach. Lets say we have the following package structure:

```
    mypackage/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── submodule1
              ├── __init__.py
              └── submodule1.py
```

Now assume that I need to use numpy inside submodule1.py. Instead of calling it inside submodule1, what I do is the following, I put the following class inside the top level init:

```
class external_modules():
    
    import numpy as np

from .submodule1 import submodule1
```

and inside submodule1.py I just call

```
from mypackage import external_modules as ext
```

and then use numpy where ever needed as ext.np. So modules are class attributes.

I know this goes somewhat against being very explicit but to help with I use name abbreviations only when packages are used too frequenctly, otherwise I keep the full name. With small packages I dont really mind it but when my packages start having several submodules, seeing os's numpies and pandas floating around everywhere not only crowds the name space of these modules but also make things look disorganized. I have however never seen this approach to organizing external modules (nor have I seen anything that is more satisfactory).

Are there any caveats to such an approach such as slowing down module loading speed for some weird reason (like trying to import numpy each time external_modules is called from somewhere, I know normally a module is not reimported if it is already imported but not sure what would happen in this case). Or weird issues if someone tries to create instances of this class.

Any suggestions on how to better handle this?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't simply add `import numpy as np` inside `submodule1.py`. This leads to a clear caveat of your approach: nobody will be able to read your code again because nobody centralizes external libraries in a single class.

Comment: Well my main motivation is when someone imports submodule1 and looks at it via dir(submodule1) I dont want it to be clutterered with external stuff and the core functionality of the submodule1 be as obvious as possible from just looking at dir.